# 80s/90s movie boy turns around and has alien face

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv

There is a scene in a movie (could have been a show?) that I watched as a young child that was so horrifying and has stuck with me for the past 30 years. I cannot figure out the movie.  Live action.

I remember the boy (white, longer hair cut common for boys in the 80s, 7-10 years old probably) was running through a field with trees in the distance. He was facing away from the camera so all you can see is his back. He slows and turns around to reveal that he now has a blue alien face.  I believe that he has turned around because someone was calling to him or looking for him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where was this and what language was it in?

Comment: This was in US, English language.

Comment: @Valerie  What is so horrifying about discovering that alien children exist?  As a rule, human children are uusally less frightening than human adults, so alien children should be less frightening than alien adults, who might possibly be quite peaceful.

Comment: Valid point, however as a human child I also found alien children to be terrifying.  ‍♀️

Answer (score 8):

*[Intruders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intruders_(miniseries))* (1992), a four hour TV miniseries.

[image: Movie poster for Intruders]

He was playing in the yard and a boy waved to him to follow him. He leads him to a saucer in the woods and turns around and has an alien face but partially human. This is the same movie where aliens pose as cable men and walk through the walls of the woman's house to get her.

### Trailer

### The boy turning around

[image: An image showing the boy turning and showing his alien face]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I edited in a link, and YouTube videos of the trailer, and that scene, for as long as they stay up.